# Compare two ranges than copy the similar cells to another range

Tags: excel, vba

I got two ranges that contains numbers. I want all the similar and distinct numbers between range 1 and range 2 to be copy in range 3. I hope I'm clear enough!

```
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range

    'the endRng is because the lengh varies

    Set rng1 = Range("A250:" & endRng1)
    Set rng2 = Range("B250:" & endrng2)
    Set rng3 = Range("D250:" & endrng3)

    Dim match As Boolean
    Dim compte As Integer
    match = False
    Dim cell1 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range

    For Each cell1 In rng2
        For Each cell2 In rng1
            If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then

                match = True
              'Here I want to copy all similar and distinct value in rng1 and rng2 to rng3

            Else



            End If
        Next cell2
    Next cell1
```

Comment: And the current problem is?  Please explain the error you are getting and on which line.

Comment: I'm unable to get the similar and distinct value between range 1 and range 2 then copy it to range 3

Comment: If range 1 = 1,2,3,4    range 2 = 2,4,5   Range 3 must contains 2,4.  I've tried rng3 = cell1.Value but I get 4,4 (In the exemple above)

Comment: I understand what you want. what is your code doing/not doing, that is in error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this does what you want. You don't want to define rng3 up front but build it up based on the values that match in both ranges.

```
Sub x()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim endRng1, endRng2

'the endRng is because the lengh varies

Set rng1 = Range("A250:" & endRng1)
Set rng2 = Range("B250:" & endRng2)
'Set rng3 = Range("D250:" & endrng3)

Dim compte As Long
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range

For Each cell1 In rng2
    For Each cell2 In rng1
        If cell1.Value = cell2.Value Then
            If rng3 Is Nothing Then
                Set rng3 = cell1
            Else
                Set rng3 = Union(rng3, cell1)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell2
Next cell1

Range("D250").Resize(rng3.Count) = rng3.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it worked. It's actually more efficient to use Match (or Find) which would avoid one of the loops. I can post alternative code if you're interested.